# Select on multiple pipes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe

I have object will multiple pipes (bidirectional). What i need is to wait until in any of these pipes any objects show up. Unfortunately, when i try to do something like this:

```
from multiprocess import Pipe
import select

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, pipe1, pipe2):
        self.__my_pipes = [pipe1, pipe2]

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            ready, _, _ = select.select(self.__my_pipes, [], [])
            #and some stuff
```

I'm getting error

```
OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Constructor of MyClass is invoked like this:

```
pipe1, pipe2 = Pipe()
pipe3, pipe4 = Pipe()
obj = MyClass(pipe1, pipe3)
```

According to documentation, select.select requires ints (file descriptors) or objects with parameterless function fileno() (which Connection objects created with Pipe() have got). I have even tried to do:

```
w, r = os.pipe()
read, _, _ = select.select([w, r], [], [])
```

but error was the same. Any ideads?

EDIT

Yes, currently i'm working on Windows, but it looks like i'll have to change platform ... Thanks for answers. I have this thoughts that on Windows those file descirptors might not work, but i wasn't sure. Now i know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `select()` with an array containing `Connection` objects as used by `multiprocessing`.  (Btw, you were writing `multiprocess` in your source, but I guess it should be `multiprocessing`.)  `select()`, however, cannot handle these.

Try using `pipe1.fileno()` etc. instead; this is a file number (an int) and select is perfectly capable of working with these.

EDIT:

If you are working on windows, file numbers are not supported by `select()` (bad luck).  I cannot help then.  Unless you would be willing to go multithreading and have one thread for each thing to wait on; that should also work on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running on Windows?

[The docs say](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/select.html#select.select):

> File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.

Honestly, I don't know anything for polling / selecting from standard library that works on Windows. Possibly [Python for Windows Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) provide a nice `WaitForMultipleObjects` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make use of the pipe's own function poll or it's variables readable,writable

```
pipe1.poll()
pipe1.writable
pipe1.readable
```

it's not the same, but a code like this could do what you want:

```
def return_pipes(pipes):
    readable = []
    writable = []
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.readable:
            readable.append(pipe)
        if pipe.writable:
            writable.append(pipe)
    return(readable,writable)

readable,writable = return_pipes([pipe1,pipe2])
```

"readable" and "writable" will then be lists with pipes that are read or writable. You could expand the function to make it do a bit more what you want or just iterate over the function a lot.